# Navigator.pop with argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have the route

```
Navigator.pop(context,"/second");
```

However, I need to pass the argument `contact`. I know this works fine with `arguments:` for `popAndPushNamed`, but I'm not sure how to do it for `pop/popUntil` etc.

```
Contact contact = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

The code is on an edit page. On the `onPress`, it directs back to the previous page showing the updated document fields.

Comment: do you want to pop or push a new route? because pop doesn't have a parameter for a named route, the second parameter is to send a value to the previous screen

Comment: Oh right. I'd like to pop with the `contact` being passed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Navigator.pop(context, "/second")` will pop the current route and return the `String` "/second" as the result of that route.
If this route was pushed, it received a `Future` that will resolve with this `String` when it's popped.

If you would have your page that pops the result on /myNextRoute, the following snippet, would return "/second" as the result.

```
final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/myNextRoute");
```

So I assume you would want to return the `contact`, so just use

```
// on the first screen
final contact = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/myNextRoute");

// on the second screen
Navigator.pop(context, contact);
```